# Dispositivos móviles no se conectan a mi web local (XAMPP)

Tags: web, xampp

Estoy trabajando en una página web y he instalado el xampp. Todo va bien en el ordenador, veo la web y todo, pero cuando me conecto con un dispositivo móvil o table, no me carga la página, pongo la direccion ip de mi equipo pero se queda cargando y no se une. (estando en la misma red)

Ya he trabajado con xampp antes y no me ha dado ningún problema, el pc con el que estoy trabajando es nuevo.

Comment: Comprueba la configuración de tu firewall. Deberás permitir el acceso al puerto 80/443 desde el exterior. ¿Qué versión de windows usas? ¿qué tipo de red tienes configurada para tu tarjeta de red o wifi? Es decir, ¿hogar, trabajo o pública?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en el firewall, que impide la conexión.

Para que funcione correctamente tenemos 2 opciones, desconectarlo por completo (nada recomendable) o permitir el acceso a la aplicación.

Para permitir el acceso a la aplicación abrimos el panel de aplicaciones permitidas.

Presionamos tecla windows, escribimos "firewall" y hacemos clic en los "Permitir a una aplicación a traves de firewall de Windows".

[image: foto 2]

Una vez abierto el panel, hacemos clic en el botón de "Cambiar configuración" y buscamos "Apache HTTP Server", marcamos la casilla de la izquierda y le damos a aceptar

[image: foto1]

Hacemos clic en el recuadro de la izquierda:

[image: foto3]